# how port forwarding in Huawei CPE B310

Tags: router, port-forwarding, web-hosting

I have an internet connection via a **4G LTE CPE B310** router from Huawei, its local IP is 192.168.8.1, my laptop is the only user connected via wifi (I can use wired Ethernet) and it its assigned local IP is 192.168.8.100.

Device name: B310s-927

Hardware version: WL1B310TM

Software version: 21.300.01.00.1269

In order to test the hosting of a website in my laptop, I did the following:

1- I installed on my Windows 7 the 64bit version of WAMP web server 2.5 (Apache-2.4.9, Mysql-5.6.17 andphp5.5.12)

2- I configured WAMP to listen to HTTP port 3388 (to avoid any blocking of port 80 or 8080 from ISP side)

3- I added an entry in the Windows firewall to allow incoming requests on this port (TCP and UDP).

4- I registered a free TLD

5- I registered to **dynu.com** as a DDNS service provider, where I setup a port forwarding transfer to my port 3388 (to avoid writing the port number when accessing my website), I installed the DDNS client application on Windows (my router supports only the dyn.org service and doesn't allows customized DDNS services)

---

The missing part is the port forwarding in the router part.
Here I'm stuck and I don't know if my router supports or not this feature.

I didn't find an explicit port forwarding feature in the configuration panel of my router. hence, I found two features that I'm not sure if they do the same job.

I attached screen shots of these features, one of them is called "virtual server" that I already added some entries as an example.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0jXetgoGD96MWpQOXplRFBpZzQ/view?usp=sharing

The second one is called "special applications" used for video games servers and so on.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0jXetgoGD96YWRtME0yRnBfMTA/view?usp=sharing

---

I hope you have all the necessary information to help me know if I can test web hosting with my hardware and software setup.

Comment: This can only work if your ISP provides you with a public IP, many LTE deployments will have you behind NAT. Check what you WAN IP is listed as to find out.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved mine.

Go to your favorite browser and enter your **Huawei b310s-927** IP address eg. `192.168.8.1` or `192.168.0.1` depending on your routers IP.

It will bring up a page for downloading there mobile app, skip it by clicking the link below that says "**Web Page**".

On next page, click **settings** and then enter your admin login and password which can be found below the router or user manual.

```
The default is username:admin password:admin
```

Next is on the quick setup navigation, click security and then click virtual server.

[image: This is an Example].

On virtual server, enter your configuration. If you still experience fault, click firewall switch and disable it. Although mine works with firewall on.

That's all you need to do.